# MicroPython REPL on Nodemcu not responding

Tags: command-line, python, wifi-configuration, arduino

I have been trying micropython on esp8266 nodemcu. I have flashed the nodemcu with micropython firmware and verified the operation. But when I try to open the REPL prompt in Thonny IDE, I get the following error

Could not connect to REPL.
Make sure your device has suitable firmware and is not in bootloader mode!
Bytes read: b''
Disconnecting.

I am getting similar errors on PyCharm IDE, picocom and uPyCraft. The laptop is detecting a device and powering it, but I am not able to upload or view any files.

Comment: Do you get more information when you connect with a serial program, eg. Putty?